# c# wpf Environment.GetCommandLineArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line-arguments, mutex

I am using Mutex to only allow it to run once but when i call Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() with url, but when it triggers, it runs another instance for url. I have a object created at runtime. When another instance created with url i cannot access this object.

```
URL:app:registerapp=<line> <username>123</username><transfertype>0</transfertype> </line>"
```

this is my url.With this url i can register 123 user, on browser.

Code without mutex:

```
string[] argumentsofcmd = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        if (argumentsofcmd != null && argumentsofcmd.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in argumentsofcmd)
            {  
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && ((System.Uri.UnescapeDataString((item.Trim().ToLower())).Contains("app:registerapp"))))
                {
                    
                    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("app\\registerappparameter", true);
                    key.SetValue("registerapp", item);
                    mainvmappxaml.SendMessageToShowMainWindowAsync("registerapp");
                }
            }

        }
```

Code with mutex:

```
public App()
    {   // Try to grab mutex

        bool createdNew;
        _mutex = new Mutex(true, "app", out createdNew);

        if (!createdNew)
        {

            string[] argumentsofcmd = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

         if (argumentsofcmd != null && argumentsofcmd.Length > 0)
         {
            foreach (var item in argumentsofcmd)
            {  
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && ((System.Uri.UnescapeDataString((item.Trim().ToLower())).Contains("app:registerapp"))))
                {
                    
                    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("app\\registerappparameter", true);
                    key.SetValue("registerapp", item);
                    mainvmappxaml.SendMessageToShowMainWindowAsync("registerapp");
                }
            }

          }
           
            Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            // ActivateApp(current.ProcessName);


            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
            {
                if (process.Id != current.Id)
                {
                    //ActivateOtherWindow();
                    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);

                    break;
                }
            }
            Current.Shutdown();
        }
        else
        {

            Exit += CloseMutexHandler;
        }
}
```

I tried GetCommandLineArgs codes outside the mutex codes. But i couldn't trigger at all.

1: How can i trigger GetCommandLineArgs codes outside the mutex when app is working if possible?

2: İnside mutex when i trigger commanline why it creates another instance. I think it shouldnt create another instance. How can i prevent this from happening. If it is normal to create another instance, how can i access the object created in runtime before trigger.

Thanks for help.